# Android Getting pdf file's path from my app

Tags: android, file, pdf, mime-types, intentfilter

I am doing an android application. The objective is given below.

> **Objective:**

If the user want to share the pdf (or) image file form anywhere in their android mobile device, they will have the option of my app in the share list. I want to know, whether the user selected the pdf file or an image. For that I used the following code.

> In **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.share.FileActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />                
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> In **FileActivity.java**, to get the selected file URI

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent myintent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = myintent.getExtras();
    String action = myintent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {
        if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            URI uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            .
            .
        }
    }
}
```

> **Issue:**

If I open pdf from the file explorer I am getting the correct URI as "**file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf**". so that I can identify as pdf or image.

But If I open the pdf file from the google drive app, I am getting the following URI "**content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3Du4Ss-AYnclkKv-lfNmA3wY7YBbb_JxRfayDTvfQfHWokHkoy%0A**". So I couldn't identify the selected file.

How can I get the file type from the above URI. Help me to fix this issue?

Comment: not the answer and a off topic but I think it is considered better to declare different intent filter tags for different types.

Comment: ContentResolver.getType ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the file type from the above URI

As Selvin notes, call [`getType()` on a `ContentResolver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType%28android.net.Uri%29). You can get a `ContentResolver` by a call to `getContentResolver()` on any `Context`, such as your `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got the file type now. But How can I get the file path from the URI "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3Du4Ss-AYnclkKv-lfNmA3wY7YBbb_JxRfayDTvfQfHWokHkoy%0A"

Comment: @karthi: There is no "file path". Use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to read in the contents.